# Checkable Tool Button Icon Color Changes

Tags: qt5, c++14

I want to have effect like VLC Play Pause Button. Based on other posts, I have

1. Have created resource file with play pause icons(transparent background).
2. Have created checkable toolbutton through qt designer.
3. Have assigned icon for normal off/on through qt designer.

However, when I run the application and click button(`IsCkecked` is true), the icon turns slightly grey. I do not want background color to change. I am not sure, what is causing this behaviour as well.

Does anyone know reason behind this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set stylesheet to the play button.

Like this...
QPushButton
{
background-color:#fffff;
}

```
QPushButton:pressed
{
    background-color:#fffff; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set stylesheet to the play button.

Like this.....

```
QPushButton
{
    background-color:#fffff;(this color can be changed as you want)
}

QPushButton:pressed
{
    background-color:#fffff;( same as above )
}
```